# show left and right callout accessory in map view using map kit

Tags: iphone, ios6, storyboard, mapkit, callouts

i have a simple problem that i cant figure out the answer to. i am extracting the long and lat of locations from within the plist and placing them on the map view. this part works just fine. pins show and the title and the subtitle (again from the plist) show as well. here is the code that for my view controller .h class:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "Annotation.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end


#define WIMB_LATITUDE 51.434783;
#define WIMB_LONGITUDE -0.213428;


#define ARSENAL_LATITUDE 51.556899;
#define ARSENAL_LONGITUDE -0.106403;

#define CHELSEA_LATITUDE 51.481314;
#define CHELSEA_LONGITUDE -0.190129;


#define THE_SPAN 0.10f;

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize myMapView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

MKCoordinateRegion myRegion;
CLLocationCoordinate2D center;
center.latitude = ARSENAL_LATITUDE;
center.longitude = ARSENAL_LONGITUDE;
MKCoordinateSpan span;
span.latitudeDelta = THE_SPAN;
span.longitudeDelta = THE_SPAN;
myRegion.center = center;
myRegion.span=span;
[myMapView setRegion:myRegion animated:YES];

NSMutableArray *annotations = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Stadiums" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSArray *anns = [dict objectForKey:@"Stadiums"];
NSLog(@"read1");

for(int i = 0; i < [anns count]; i++) {
    NSLog(@"read2");
    float realLatitude = [[[anns objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Latitude"] floatValue];
    float realLongitude = [[[anns objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Longitude"] floatValue];
    NSLog(@"read3");

    Annotation *myAnnotation = [[Annotation alloc] init];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D theCoordinate;
    theCoordinate.latitude = realLatitude;
    theCoordinate.longitude = realLongitude;
    myAnnotation.coordinate = theCoordinate;
    myAnnotation.title = [[anns objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Title"];
    myAnnotation.subtitle = [[anns objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Subtitle"];
    [myMapView addAnnotation:myAnnotation];
    [annotations addObject:myAnnotation];
    //[myAnnotation release];
}

}

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)map viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
static NSString *AnnotationViewID = @"annotationViewID";

MKAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKAnnotationView *)[myMapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:AnnotationViewID];

if (annotationView == nil)
{
    annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationViewID];
}

UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
[rightButton addTarget:nil action:nil forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;

UIImageView *IconView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"toilets.png"]];
annotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = IconView;

annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
annotationView.annotation = annotation;
return annotationView;
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

my issue is that the left and right callout accessories never gets called. when pressing on the pin i just get the title and the subtitle. i have tried so many different ways but cant seem to solve this issue. can any one please help me repair this code so i can get the accessories to show.

thanks a million

p.s. i am using iOS 6 and storyboard and the project is based on iphone only.

Comment: Are you sure your viewForAnnotation method is getting called?  The way it's written, it's creating plain MKAnnotationViews (instead of MKPinAnnotationViews) with no image set so they would be invisible.  If your annotations are appearing as red pins, it's because the method isn't getting called in the first place (probably because the map view's delegate isn't set) and the map view creates default pin views.  Also note that if you intend to use the calloutAccesoryControlTapped delegate method, you should not do a manual addTaget on the accessory button.

Comment: @AnnaKarenina, thanks for the advice. I'm going back to this project tonight and I may ask you for some help after I twicking the code. You probably are right about the delegate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ah, got it. as Anna was right in her hint about the delegate not being set. i was setting the delegate in the wrong way. all i had to do was add the  to my view controller header view rather than trying to input it in my annotation view and then call the delegate in view controller's view did load method to self, like this: myMapView.delegate = self;
the code was working all along, but because of the missing delegate my view for annotation was not getting fired. once again thanks to Anna Karennina for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

You should implement the left and right callout in `– mapView:didSelectAnnotationView:` delegate method.
So, your code

```
annotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = IconView;
```

`annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;` Must go in above method. 
Try to call on default annotations. You will get it all clear.

Hope this helps.:)

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I already answered my question . It was the delegate method which I was declaring in the wrong class. But thanks for trying.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to implement the following method:

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
```

Comment: that is the method to call when there is an accessory button showing in annotation already. my issue is that the annotation does not show the accessory button which i declared in view for annotation.